# Sorting of Month Columns Beginning with wrong month

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, columnsorting

I have a problem with sorting my columns in my matrix by month order.  I have read many, many posts on problems where the results are alphabetical but none where it starts at the wrong month.

I am using a calculated field called MonthSort using expression:

```
=FORMAT(Fields!createdon.Value,"yyyyMM")
```

And I have then  Sorted by MonthSort in the Column Group (Group Properties) Sorting Option.

[image: Design Screen Example]

This is something that I have used frequently and in the past it has always sorted from Jan to Dec correctly.  However this time it is sorting from November to October.

In my query I am pulling data with the following WHERE clause and I am wondering if this is affecting the starting month.

```
AND (createdon BETWEEN '2016/11/25' AND DATEADD(minute, - 1, @EndDate + 1))
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

[image: Results Example]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you change the sort expression to =FORMAT(Fields!createdon.Value,"MM")

Comment: Your expression takes the year into account too so it's ordering correctly as 201611 then 201612, 201701 201702 and so on. What do you expect the output to look like? Where would the 2016 values show?  If you really just want the months in order you probably don't even need your calculated field as you can just sort by the CreatedMonth column in your dataset.

Comment: Thankyou @Schmocken - that was all that was needed.  I removed the "yyyy" and left just the "MM" and it has worked perfectly and the months now run Jan to Dec with the years populated underneath each other.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know how mark @Schmocken's comment as the correct answer

Comment: Schmoken has added his/her as an answer so you can mark that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity, what happens if you change the sort expression to `=FORMAT(Fields!createdon.Value,"MM")`

Comment: Thankyou @Schmocken - that was all that was needed. I removed the "yyyy" and left just the "MM" and it has worked perfectly and the months now run Jan to Dec with the years populated underneath each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort expression

```
=FORMAT(Fields!createdon.Value,"yyyyMM")
```

gets you data in the format 201611, 201612, 201701,... so the sort works correctly.

Comment: You assume that the any row grouping has allowed multiple years on one row. You may be right, but you would need the OP to confirm.